# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML') Error

Tags: javascript

```
    let creatPost = document.getElementById('CP');

    let postNames = document.querySelectorAll("#po");
    console.log(postNames);

    let postDatas = document.querySelectorAll("#dat");
    console.log(postDatas);

    let editBtns = document.querySelectorAll("#editBu");
    console.log(editBtns);

    let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll("#deleteBu");
    console.log(deleteBtns);


    postName = Array.from(postNames);
    postData =Array.from(postDatas);

    for (let i = 0; i <= postData.length; i++) {
        let PD = postData[i]
        PD.innerHTML = "title"  //   i am geeting error on this line
    };
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= postName.length; i++) {
        PN = postName[i].innerHTML = "post " + ( i + 1 );  //  i am geeting error on this line
    };
```

there is an error appear in console of chrome "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')"

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#po");` etc doesn't make much sense. Ids are meant to be unique on the page so `querySelectorAll` is rather pointless. Use `querySelector` instead, and make sure you only have one element with an id, or switch to classes (in which case you _can_ use `querySelectorAll`.) If you add your markup to your question (as a [mcve]) we can debug the code easier.

Comment: thanks for your effort i will edit my code by points that you are mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `postData` has, say, 6 elements, they will be numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

But this loop will address numbers 0 to 6 (note the "<=" instead of "<"):

```
for (let i = 0; i <= postData.length; i++) {
```

when it hits the sixth element, postData[i] will be undefined, and its innerHTML won't be settable.

Comment: I thank you with all my heart for your efforts with me.